# jQuery Ajax Returning Error on Click but Runs fine with Document.Ready?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml-parsing

Update: seems to work fine in IE, but not in Opera, FF or Chrome...

I am trying to use javascript to write a simple way to immport data into sqlite using bind. My click function is not working on my simple ajax request. I am confused here... As always, this works just fine:

```
$("#showDB").click(function(){alert("CLICKED!")});
```

This works just fine:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'dv.xml',
                dataType: 'xml',
                success: parseXml,  
                error: function() {
                    alert('XML file not found.');

                }
            });
            function parseXml(xml) {
                    //alert('XML file found.');
                    $(xml).find('Employee').each(function(){
                        var name = $(this).find('name').text();
                        var email = $(this).find('email').val();
                        var jobtitle = $(this).find('jobtitle').val();
                        var address = $(this).find('address').val();
                        var workphone = $(this).find('workphone').val();
                        var homephone = $(this).find('homephone').val();
                        var cellphone = $(this).find('cellphone').val();
                        var fax = $(this).find('fax').val();
                        var contractor = $(this).find('contractor').val();

                        alert(name);

                    });
             }

      });
```

But when i want to click in order to run my ajax request it returns my error Alert "XML file not found."

```
 $("#showDB").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'dv.xml',
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: parseXml,  
            error: function() {
                alert('XML file not found.');

            }
        });
        function parseXml(xml) {
                //alert('XML file found.');
                $(xml).find('Employee').each(function(){
                    var name = $(this).find('name').text();
                    var email = $(this).find('email').val();
                    var jobtitle = $(this).find('jobtitle').val();
                    var address = $(this).find('address').val();
                    var workphone = $(this).find('workphone').val();
                    var homephone = $(this).find('homephone').val();
                    var cellphone = $(this).find('cellphone').val();
                    var fax = $(this).find('fax').val();
                    var contractor = $(this).find('contractor').val();

                    alert(name);

                });
         }

  });
```

Anyone know why I cannot get the xml on click? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

bad bracketing on the click code , use this :

```
$("#showDB").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'dv.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: parseXml,  
        error: function() {
            alert('XML file not found.');

        }
    });
  }); // needed to close it
```

edit: the reason the "doc" call doesnt fail is the ajax and function are encapsulated in the load annon function - the onclick code you have however was missing some closing brackets

Comment: So leave put the function outside of the click?

Comment: Yeah OR create it as an annon function like you did for the "error" handler assignment. Either way is "fine" but if the function you create is going to be used by more than 1 element, it would be a better coding practice to standardize it and make it available to "whatever elements need that interface"

Comment: I did this, but without avail... I found the issue however, my #showDB button was in a form, and thus was trying to submit the form and bunching up the whole thing...

Comment: I had the #showDB button in form tags like so:

    <form>
    <button id="showDB" type=submit>SHOW</button>
    </form>

I took the form tags off and it works fine.

 

    <button id="showDB" type=submit>SHOW</button>

 I hope this helps someone else struggling with this...